# Redirect to new domain, missing Post Value

Tags: apache, codeigniter, redirect, post, mod-rewrite

My old mobile app is using digitalocean dedicated ip to access the API from my website.

Now I have new domain for my website, but for some reason I cannot change the ip in my app to the new domain im using now.

When my app sending POST request to the API, the POST request is lost and my API can't get the value. I think its because the redirect process from the ip to domain. Is there a way to access my API from the old ip without losing POST value?

Answer (score 0):

If you are externally redirecting the POST request with a 301 or 302 status then user-agents will usually issue a GET request on the second/redirected request, so your POST data is lost.

For user-agents to preserve the *request method* through the redirect then you need to issue a 307 (Temporary) or 308 (Permanent) HTTP status code instead.

Reference:

- [MDN docs - 307 Temporary Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307)
- [MDN docs - 308 Permanent Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308)